# Combine Rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like this

```
         100  200  300
283.1   0.01 0.02 0.40
284.1   0.02 0.03 0.42
285.1   0.05 0.01 0.8
286.1   0.06 0.02 0.9
```

I need to **combine a certain number of consecutive rows** and calculate the average value for each column and a new index as the average of the indices I used, in order to obtain something like this:

```
         100   200  300
283.6   0.015 0.025 0.41  
285.6   0.055 0.015 0.85
```

**Is there a way to to this with pandas?**

Comment: On what do you want to groupby? You may want to rephrase the question and give more data for example, may be?

Comment: just consecutive rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes -- you could do this in Pandas. Here's one way to do it.

Let's say out, our initial dataframe `df` is like

```
   index   100   200   300
0  283.1  0.01  0.02  0.40
1  284.1  0.02  0.03  0.42
2  285.1  0.05  0.01  0.80
3  286.1  0.06  0.02  0.90
```

Now, calculate the length of dataframe

```
N = len(df.index)
N
4
```

We create a `grp` column -- to be used for aggregation,

where `for 2 rows` aggregation use `[x ]*2` and for `n-consecutive rows` use `[x]*n`

```
df['grp'] = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([x]*2 for x in range(0, N/2)))
df
   index   100   200   300  grp
0  283.1  0.01  0.02  0.40    0
1  284.1  0.02  0.03  0.42    0
2  285.1  0.05  0.01  0.80    1
3  286.1  0.06  0.02  0.90    1
```

Now, get the means by grouping the `grp` column like this --

```
df.groupby('grp').mean()
     index    100    200   300
grp
0    283.6  0.015  0.025  0.41
1    285.6  0.055  0.015  0.85
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

```
>>> print df
   index   100   200   300                                                        
0  283.1  0.01  0.02  0.40                                                        
1  284.1  0.02  0.03  0.42                                                        
2  285.1  0.05  0.01  0.80                                                        
3  286.1  0.06  0.02  0.90
```

break the `DataFrame` up into the portions that you want and find the `mean` of the relevant columns:

```
>>> pieces = [df[:2].mean(), df[2:].mean()]
```

then put the pieces back together using [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html):

```
>>> avgdf = pd.concat(pieces, axis=1).transpose()

   index    100    200   300                                                      
0  283.6  0.015  0.025  0.41                                                      
1  285.6  0.055  0.015  0.85
```

Alternatively, you can recombine the data with a list comprehension `[i for i in pieces]` or a generator expression:

```
>>> z = (i for i in pieces)
```

and use this to create your new `DataFrame`:

```
>>> avgdf = pd.DataFrame(z)
```

Finally, to set the index:

```
>>> avgdf.set_index('index', inplace=True)                                                 
>>> print avgdf

         100    200   300                                                         
index                                                                             
283.6  0.015  0.025  0.41                                                         
285.6  0.055  0.015  0.85
```